# Show master record once and all images php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I cannot get this to go.  I have two tables joined by ID.  I can get all the records back fine.  I need to output in php - hotel.Name once, and all the images associated with the hotel.ID. Have tried group by, show if, and still not getting it to go.  Sorry if this has been asked before, just can't seem to find it.

thanks in advance

```
SELECT
    hotel.`Name`, 
    hotel.City, 
    hotel.StateProvince, 
    hotelimage.URL, 
    hotelimage.ThumbnailURL, 
    hotelimage.ID, 
    hotel.ID
FROM
    hotelimage
    INNER JOIN hotel ON hotelimage.ID = hotel.ID
WHERE
     hotel.City = 'chicago'
GROUP BY
     hotel.ID
```

The Output.  If I take away the Group By I get all images, but for each image for each hotel I get a row with say 5 different images which I want, and 5 Hotel Names, City,State etc...  I only want the hotel Name, City, State to show once.

```
<div>
    <?php do { ?>
<table width=“600” border="1">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
<td width="338"><?php echo $row_htlImg[‘ID']; ?><br>
     <?php echo $row_htlImg[‘Name']; ?><br>
     <?php echo $row_htlImg[‘City']; ?>, 
     <?php echo $row_htlImg['StateProvince']; ?><br></td>
<td width="132"><img src="<?php echo $row_htlImg[‘URL']; ?>" width="70" height="70" alt=""/></td>
<td width="108"><?php echo $row_htlImg[’ThumbnailURL]; ?></td>
      </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>
 </div>
     <?php } while ($row_htlImg = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1)); ?>
```

Output table:

```
ID      Name            City    ST  URL
105305  The Westin      Chicago IL  http://101_b.jpg
105477  Hotel Allegro   Chicago IL  http://104_b.jpg
105679  Hampton         Chicago IL  http://184_b.jpg
106046  Park Hyatt      Chicago IL  http://100_b.jpg

    Without Group By            
105305  The Westin      Chicago IL  http://101_b.jpg
105305  The Westin      Chicago IL  http://122_b.jpg
105305  The Westin      Chicago IL  http://133_b.jpg
105305  The Westin      Chicago IL  http://144_b.jpg
105477  Hotel Allegro   Chicago IL  http://104_b.jpg
105477  Hotel Allegro   Chicago IL  http://120_b.jpg
105477  Hotel Allegro   Chicago IL  http://130_b.jpg


    Would Like it to Be         
105305  The Westin      Chicago IL  http://101_b.jpg
                                    http://122_b.jpg
                                    http://133_b.jpg
                                    http://144_b.jpg
105477  Hotel Allegro   Chicago IL  http://110_b.jpg
                                    http://120_b.jpg
                                    http://130_b.jpg
```

Comment: How does your PHP code for the output looks now?

Comment: as fabian said ... post your sql output and describe what you expect

Comment: You should really try to use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting denormalized data from the database. This is not an invalid method of getting data, but it isn't the most optimal.

However, still using this technique, it just means you only need to render the hotel's information whenever the hotel changes when you're iterating through the results. This technique does require your data have `ORDER BY hotel.ID` first, however.

```
<?php
$lastHotel = null;
while( $hotelImageRow = mysql_fetch_assoc( $recordSet ) ) {

    if( $lastHotel != $hotelImageRow['hotel.ID'] ) {
?>

        <?= htmlentities( $hotelImageRow['Name'] ) ?>
        <?= htmlentities( $hotelImageRow['City'] ) ?>
        <?= htmlentities( $hotelImageRow['StateProvince'] ) ?>

<?php
        $lastHotel = $hotelImageRow['hotel.ID'];
    } ?>

    <img src="<?= htmlentities( $hotelImageRow['ThumbnailURL'] ) ?>" />

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but I get a syntax error on this line"<?= htmlentities( $hotelImageRow['Name'] ) ?>"  unexpected '<'

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: Using PHP version 5.6.10

Comment: @pcm70 sorry, try again, see the change I made by adding the closing `?>` and opening `<?php`

Comment: I should have caught that.  Now it returns just keeps repeating the first row. The Westin Chicago IL  http://101_b.jpg, The Westin Chicago IL  http://101_b.jpg

Comment: @pcm70 compare my code to your code to see why it isn't advancing to the next row. Do you have a PHP debugger?

Comment: Had a typo.  Now I get back all the thumbnails for only the first row, and No Name, City or State

Comment: @pcm70 Just look at the algorithm I'm using and apply that to your existing code that works. Do you see how it's meant to work?